# Overlay and Image after masking are not properly positioned iOS

Tags: ios, image, camera, overlay, masking

I have added overlay on camera and taking picture of the same shape object from camera. Then apply masking on clicked image so that I will get image with that shape and other area will be white. But captured image and image after masking were not same. Here is the screenshot of final image [image]

I want this captured image with area inside star image overlay

## Overlay

```
// create view for overlay
CGRect overlayRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imagePicker.view.frame.size.width, imagePicker.view.frame.size.height-50);
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:overlayRect];

// prepare the image to overlay
UIImageView *overlayImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star"]];
overlayImage.center = overlayView.center;
overlayImage.alpha = 0.6;

[overlayView.layer setOpaque:NO];
overlayView.opaque = NO;
[overlayView addSubview:overlayImage];

imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

## Masking

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    UIImage *mask=[UIImage imageNamed:@"star"];
    UIImage *newimage=[self maskImage:[editingInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] withMask:mask];

    [self.imageView setImage:newimage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newimage, nil, nil, nil);

}
```

Comment: Put some code so one can help you.